# Can anyone tell me the nginx and kong version mapping?

Tags: nginx, kong

Can anyone tell me the nginx and kong version mapping?

I can't find this information anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the changelog you can know the bundled OpenResty version (keep in mind Kong does not run on plain, vanilla NGINX)

For example from https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#dependencies-4

you can see

> Bumped openresty from 1.19.3.2 to [1.19.9.1](https://openresty.org/en/changelog-1019009.html) #7430

And on https://openresty.org/en/changelog-1019009.html
you get nginx version

> upgraded the nginx core to 1.19.9.

Other solution running  `nginx -v` in an environment with Kong installed

Comment: it helped, but `nginx -v` don't work in envs only with kong,but `kong version -a` give information about